# How to Add Dataframe name to Columns from Multiple Dataframes

Tags: r, lapply

The goal is to rename a list of dataframes columns, but while adding the dataframe name to the new column name.

ex: from x to a_x and b_x.

Why? Because I plan to later merge the sets and would like clean ids for the columns.

```
a = data.frame(x = c(1,2))
b = data.frame(x = c(3,4))

frameList = list(a = a, b = b)

newName = c(*frameName+'_'+'x')
names = lapply(names, setNames, nm = newName)
list2env(names,.GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way for you. I looped through each data frame in `frameList` using the length of `frameList`. For column names in each data frame, I took the name of a data frame (i.e., `names(frameList)`) and past it to column names in the data frame.

```
a = data.frame(x = c(1,2), y = 1:2)
b = data.frame(x = c(3,4), y = 1:2)

frameList = list(a = a, b = b)

lapply(1:length(names(frameList)), function(x) {

       names(frameList[[x]]) <- paste(names(frameList)[x], names(frameList[[x]]), sep = "_")

       return(frameList[[x]])

})

[[1]]
  a_x a_y
1   1   1
2   2   2

[[2]]
  b_x b_y
1   3   1
2   4   2
```

Comment: @chachimouchacha Pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Or another option is `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y) setNames(x, paste(y, names(x),  sep="_")), frameList, names(frameList))
#$a   
#   a_x a_y
#1   1   1
#2   2   2

#$b
#  b_x b_y
#1   3   1
#2   4   2
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(x, y) paste(y, x, sep="_")
map2(frameList, names(frameList), ~ .x %>% 
                                      rename_all(f1, .y))
```

If we need it in the reverse order, this is more simple

```
map2(frameList, names(frameList), ~ .x %>%
                            rename_all(paste, sep="_", .y))
```

Comment: Much simpler. :)

Comment: @jazzurro  thanks, I was looking for a tidyverse option, but it seems to be having some problem with `rename_at`

Comment: They even have `rename_at`?  I do not see that in the CRAN manual version 0.7.4. Did you try to use it in `Map()`?

Comment: @jazzurro  Yes, they do have a whole army of functions.  I used it in `map2`.  updated the post

Comment: I know up to filter_at/all/if. Now I have more things to catch up. I need to learn `purrr` too. I've been lately more into learning analytical packages for my work, and I cannot learn all at the same time. Is purrr stable now?

Comment: @jazzurro  I built couple of packages for the company I work primarily using `tidyverse` packages.  The work flow is easy to read.  Of course, there are some issues like `Date` getting converted to numeric when we use `pmap` etc.  But, I think if readability is one criteria, this may be more preferred.

Comment: I see. I will start learning more. Let me check your answers as a starting point. :) Which functions are musts from purrr?

Comment: @jazzurro Mostly the `map` functions